# Adding a column to MySQL to record the Date the entry was made

Tags: mysql, sql

I am setting up a database and wanting to record when each entry was added, date only.

```
ALTER TABLE form ADD COLUMN created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I am using the above code but it also stores the time which I don't want. There is an option for DATE alone, but I can't work out how to have it auto input it like the above does.

Anyone know the query by chance? I've tried:

```
ALTER TABLE form ADD COLUMN created DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE
```

But it didn't like that and I've not found any other commands to try.

Answer (score 1):

No, only CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will work. That said, you can get easily extract the date portion of this column with the [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
SELECT
    DATE(created) as created_date
FROM
    form;
```

Here the relevant part of the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html):

> The DEFAULT clause specifies a default value for a column. With one
>   exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a
>   function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot
>   set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such
>   as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP or (as of MySQL
>   5.6.5) DATETIME column.

Answer (score 1):

If triggers are considered, this trigger should be fine:

```
CREATE trigger def_date before INSERT ON form
FOR each
ROW SET NEW.date = CURDATE( )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second `ALTER` statement don't work cause you can't use function/expression as `default`. from MySQL documentation [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)

> The DEFAULT clause specifies a default value for a column. With one
>   exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a
>   function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot
>   set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such
>   as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column

So essentially, you can only use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default.